# the induced trivial $*$ homomorphism

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A=c_{0}\oplus \mathbb{K}$,$I=c_{0}$ is the closed ideal of $A$,there is an induced $*$ homomorphism
$\phi:A/I\rightarrow M(I)/I$,where $M(I)$ is the multiplier algebra of $I$.$\phi(a+I)=(L_{a},R_{a})+I$.I have no idea about showing $\phi=0$.

Comment: What are $L_a$ and $R_a$?  What is $\Bbb K$?  What is $L$?  This question looks tantalizing, but without the definitions everything, I can't really understand it.

Comment: @RobertLewis: $L_a$ and $R_a$ are the left and right multipliers by the element $a$; $\mathbb K$ is the C$^*$-algebra of compact operators on a separable Hilbert space. This very very standard terminology, particularly taking into account the tags used for the question.

Comment: @MartinArgerami :  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @MartinArgerami,excuse me Pro Argerami,I am still confused that $\phi=0$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows by the universal property of the multiplier algebra.

More generally, let $A,I,B$ be C*-algebras and $A = I \oplus B$. Then $I$ is an ideal in $A$ and the inclusion $I \to M(I)$ can be uniquely extended to a $*$-hom.  $A \to M(I)$. However, such an extension is given by the projection $\pi_I : I \oplus B\to I$. So the map
$$
 A \to M(I) /I
$$
is already $0$ and therefore also the map $A/I \to M(I)/ I$.

Comment: I don't understand why the extension is given by the projection $\pi_{I}$

Comment: The key point is that there is a **unique** $*$-homorphism $\pi:A\to M (I) $ with $\pi|_I=\operatorname {id}_I $. If you had two such $\pi_1,\pi_2$, then for any  $x\in I $ and $a\in A $,$$\pi_1 (a)x=\pi_1 (a)\pi_1 (x)=\pi_1 (ax)=\pi_2 (ax)=\pi_2 (a)\pi_2 (x)=\pi_2 (a)x. $$So $\pi_1 (a)=\pi_2 (a) $. As $\pi_I $ in the answer is such a map, it is "the" map; so, $\pi_I $ is $a\longmapsto (L_a,R_a) $.